# Unfortunately <App-Name> has stopped & show error message "include Java exception stack in crash report" in logcat

Tags: android, android-webview

When Creating webview with splash screen as well as progressbar then in **MainActivity.java** having code shown below

```
package com.shopence.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private WebView mWebView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://shopence.com/");
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    /** Inflating the current activity's menu with res/menu/items.xml */
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    /** Getting the actionprovider associated with the menu item whose id is share */
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).getActionProvider();

    /** Setting a share intent */
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

/** Returns a share intent */
private Intent getDefaultShareIntent(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "shopence.com");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Welcome To Shopence");
    return intent;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

In activity_main.xml having code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/progressbar_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="161dp"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:max="500"
            android:progress="0"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Loading data..." />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#8FBC8F" />
</LinearLayout>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:divider="#00000000"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:persistentDrawingCache="scrolling"
    android:smoothScrollbar="false" >
</ListView>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

After Running App it generate a message **Unfortunately My App has stopped** in AVD.But in **logcat** it shown error like that & app becomes crash in emulator.

```
2690-2690/com.shopence.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                              Process: com.shopence.myapp, PID: 2690
                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
                                                                  at com.shopence.myapp.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:58)
                                                                  at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2846)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:567)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:939)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:271)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: you have a issue with your Share Intent---> mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());

Comment: check this----> http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/using-shareactionprovider-in-action-bar/

Comment: So How could I resolve problem regarding that code?

Comment: In this code mShareActionProvider is declared globally at the top and you didn't....

Answer (score 0):

`mShareActionProvider` is not getting initialized properly. It is null and hence the NPE.

```
mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());
```

This is the line where you get a NULL: Correct this so that you get the shareActionProvider correctly.

```
 /** Getting the actionprovider associated with the menu item whose id is share */
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).getActionProvider();
```

After running that program in **Logcat** shows error like

```
E/SysUtils: ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
01-04 11:32:28.599 1996-1996/com.shopence.myapp W/chromium:     [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(285)] locale_file_path.empty()
01-04 11:32:29.139 1996-1996/com.shopence.myapp E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
01-04 11:32:29.151 1996-1996/com.shopence.myapp E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
01-04 11:32:29.161 1996-1996/com.shopence.myapp E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(327)] No suitable EGL configs found.
01-04 11:32:29.161 1996-1996/com.shopence.myapp E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_android.cc(23)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
01-04 11:32:29.165 1996-1996/com.shopence.myapp E/chromium: [ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(698)] GLSurface::InitializeOneOff failed
01-04 11:32:29.316 1996-1996/com.shopence.myapp E/DataReductionProxySettingListener: No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp
01-04 11:32:29.560 1996-2006/com.shopence.myapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.744ms
01-04 11:32:29.578 1996-2151/com.shopence.myapp W/AudioManagerAndroid: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
01-04 11:32:29.902 1996-1996/com.shopence.myapp W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
01-04 11:32:29.996 1996-1996/com.shopence.myapp W/AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
01-04 11:32:30.887 1996-2012/com.shopence.myapp I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 7248(504KB) AllocSpace objects, 4(100KB) LOS objects, 44% free, 2MB/3MB, paused 4.956ms total 226.065ms
01-04 11:32:30.895 1996-2012/com.shopence.myapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.480ms
01-04 11:32:32.551 1996-2149/com.shopence.myapp W/chromium: [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_config.cc(423)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
01-04 11:32:32.987 1996-1996/com.shopence.myapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-04 11:32:33.415 1996-1996/com.shopence.myapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-04 11:32:36.872 1996-2006/com.shopence.myapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 262.669ms
01-04 11:32:37.319 1996-1996/com.shopence.myapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 81 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-04 11:32:37.670 1996-2200/com.shopence.myapp A/chromium:  [FATAL:gl_surface_android.cc(58)] Check failed: kGLImplementationNone != GetGLImplementation() (0 vs. 0)
01-04 11:32:39.665 1996-1996/com.shopence.myapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 89 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-04 11:32:39.924 1996-2200/com.shopence.myapp W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
01-04 11:32:39.924 1996-2200/com.shopence.myapp W/google-breakpad: Chrome build fingerprint:
01-04 11:32:39.924 1996-2200/com.shopence.myapp W/google-breakpad: 1.0
01-04 11:32:39.924 1996-2200/com.shopence.myapp W/google-breakpad: 1
01-04 11:32:39.924 1996-2200/com.shopence.myapp W/google-breakpad: 023f32a1-4862-425f-a49b-e5b1792614ed
01-04 11:32:39.924 1996-2200/com.shopence.myapp W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
01-04 11:32:39.925 1996-2200/com.shopence.myapp E/chromium: ### WebView Version 44.0.2403.119 (code 246011900)
01-04 11:32:39.927 1996-2200/com.shopence.myapp A/libc: Fatal signal 6  (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 2200 (GpuThread)
```

Comment: So How could I resolve that problem that means remove ShareActionProvider or initialize as local

Comment: declare at global level `private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;` refer this page for an example: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/using-shareactionprovider-in-action-bar/

Answer (score 0):

Did you add **android:actionProviderClass** in your R.menu.menu_main like below

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Share"
        android:actionProviderClass=
            "android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
...
</menu>
```

then use this code in onCreateOptionsMenu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate menu resource file.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.share_menu, menu);

// Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

// Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();

// Return true to display menu

/** Setting a share intent */
mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());
return true;

}
```